# Downloading "Apps" in an App?

Tags: ios, iphone, app-store, itunes

I'm working on a new App and I'm nearly finished!

In my App I install new "Apps" (not really Apps, but I don't know how to call it), using an URLScheme.

So you install an "App" using an URLScheme (An "App" includes the Icon and what the App does, for example it downloads an HTML content to my App and by clicking on the Icon which is now installed, it opens the HTML content):

So my Question is, am I able to publish such an App?
Or do I get problems with Apple?

Comment: You'll have to explain in more detail... what "apps" do you install with your app?

Comment: So, using the URLScheme you are able to install "apps" with an icon and what the App does, e.g. URLScheme (to open another App), or a link for the built-in browser, or for downloading HTML content.

Comment: My mind powers cannot comprehend this question. Sorry.

Comment: It seems you are looking for a solution to install an application within your application ? Is it?

Comment: No, I already have the solution, the problem is publishing my App, and before I send it to Apple, I want to know if I get problems by publishing such an App?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Quote from [Apple's App Review Guidelines](https://developer.apple.com/appstore/resources/approval/guidelines.html):

```
2.7    Apps that download code in any way or form will be rejected
2.8    Apps that install or launch other executable code will be rejected
```